# What is the difference between image width and max width when inside div with specified dimensions?

Tags: html, css

I've got image element inside another div element:

```
<p align="right" class="bottom_right icon_image">
    <img src="img/icon_image.png" alt="myartwork" class="child_image">
</p>
```

Now when I set child element to be max-width, I get father's side but when I set width 100%, I get screen width. Why is that?

```
.icon_image{
    height: 25vh;
    width: auto;                
}
.child_image{
    max-height: 100%; //When set tp height: 100%, behaves crazy.
}
```

EDIT: .bottom_right is attached:

```
    .bottom_right{
            position: fixed;
        }
        .bottom_right{
            right: 5%;
            bottom: 5%; 
        }
        .bottom_right:hover{
            right: 9%;
            bottom: 9%;
        }
```

Comment: You might want to synchronise/edit the question with the provided code. In the question you are asking about width, and in the code it's height. This can help future searches.

Answer (score 1):

This is not enough information to debug this issue. I encourage you to put this code into a Codepen first. The code you supplied pasted directly into a Codepen does not re-create the issue.

Comment: okay I guess I have to ramp up on asking questions here :D Thanks! I will improve the question.

Comment: It's all good. It's just hard to answer a vague question like "it behaves crazy" when the code you supplied works fine. There is something else affecting it, so you either need to provide more context or provide a minimal code sample that re-creates your issue. How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Your `<p>` tag indicates `class="bottom_right icon_image"`. Is there another class element on your CSS document called 'bottom_right'? Or, was this meant to refer to something else?
Thank you for the added snippit. This is my recommendation:
Either the .icon_image or .child_image should be edited to only include "max-width: 100%; height:auto;". This will allow the width and height of the image to automatically adjust according to the viewer's screen size. It, essentially, mimics a Vector graphic image.  If you set this to .img (as in my example), all of your images will have this effect. That eliminates the need to for the .icon_image and .child_image classes. Add your width/height data to the HTML image tag, but you no longer need to indicate a style class (it will automatically get the .img style, right?)  Note: no changes to the .bottom_right class.
The resulting code should look like this:

```
<p align="right" class="bottom_right">
    <img src="img/icon_image.png" width="" height="" alt="myartwork">
</p>

.img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }

.bottom_right{
        position: fixed;
    }
    .bottom_right{
        right: 5%;
        bottom: 5%; 
    }
    .bottom_right:hover{
        right: 9%;
        bottom: 9%;
    }
```

Comment: guess your answer will be removed, you can check it meanwhile at geniestills.com - I have everything online now there, the bottom_right includes everything which is in the right bottom of the screen (position, animation, hover effects).

Comment: Would you please provide the .bottom_right CSS code snippet so we can answer this better?

Comment: oh ooh okay now I understand